# Choose skin to load at runtime with Flex

Tags: apache-flex

How can I choose an external skin to load (SWF) for my application BEFORE any others skin to be applied ?

Something like :

```
<fx:Style source="my.url/"+ hereVariable + ".css" />
```

or with `styleManager.loadStyleDeclarations2(...)` on initialize or preinitialize events but it always crashes before my dynamic skin is loaded.

> Error: Required skin part XXX cannot be found.

but my skin part XXX is in my SWF file that I'm trying to load...

Thanks for any help

Comment: Are you talking about a skin for the overall Application, or individual components within the app?

Comment: I'm talking about a skin for the overall Application (for each component).

Comment: every component needs a skin but you are not providing one for your Application until the app is already running. You'll need to provide a default skin for app startup and then load the custom skin when app is ready.

Answer (score 0):

last option make ur own style object from script and use it with stylemanager

Comment: Seems I can't because I externalize all my skins in a SWF file but when Flex launch its initialization process, it's look like it expects some default skin but I haven't. One solution is probably to load default SWF file and override it after but it's ugly and I load 2 skins so it's longuer.

Answer (score -1):

var path:String = "my.url/"+ hereVariable + ".css";

Comment: Yes but how can I assign this variable to fx:style ? There is no id to do that.

Comment: <fx:Style source="{path}"/>